# Can I make NA or missing values transparent in a tmap plot using a list of rasters

Tags: r, raster, tmap

In the following example code where I attempt to plot two rasters using `tmap` functions, I cannot seem to produce a single plot where the NA or non-existent values are transparent.

My aim here is to have all the raster `values > 0.5` display but none of the missing values.

Please assist.

Here is my current code:

```
# setup -------------------------------------------------------------------

library(raster)

library(tmap)

# produce the data --------------------------------------------------------

# first raster

set.seed(123)

raster1 <- raster(matrix(runif(100),
                         nrow = 10))

extent(raster1) <- extent(-180,
                          -170,
                          0, 
                          10) 

projection(raster1) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

# second raster

set.seed(456)

raster2 <- raster(matrix(runif(100),
                         nrow = 10))

extent(raster2) <- extent(-180, 
                          -170,
                          0, 
                          10)

projection(raster2) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

rasters <- 
  list(raster1,
       raster2) %>% 
  map(
    ~ setMinMax(.x)) %>% 
  set_names("1",
            "2")

# function for reclassifying min. values

replace_values <- function(raster_layer) {
  
  raster_layer[raster_layer <= 0.5] <- NA
  
  return(raster_layer)
}

# plot the data -----------------------------------------------------------

# applying the function to each raster in the list

map(rasters, replace_values) + 
  
  #   $`1`
  # class      : RasterLayer 
  # dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
  # resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
  # extent     : -180, -170, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
  # crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
  # source     : memory
  # names      : layer 
  # values     : 0.5115055, 0.9942698  (min, max)
  # 
# 
# $`2`
# class      : RasterLayer 
# dimensions : 10, 10, 100  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
# extent     : -180, -170, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
# source     : memory
# names      : layer 
# values     : 0.5018561, 0.9930836  (min, max)

tm_shape(rasters$`1`) +
  tm_raster(
    n = 3,
    colorNA = NA,
    alpha = 0.5,
    palette = "Blues") +
  
  tm_shape(rasters$`2`) +
  tm_raster(
    n = 3,
    colorNA = NA,
    alpha = 0.5,
    palette = "Reds") +
  
  tm_scale_bar(
    text.size = 1,
    position = c("left", 
                 "bottom")) +
  
  tm_compass(
    position = c("right", 
                 "top"), 
    size = 1.5,
    text.size = 0.5) +
  
  tm_layout(
    frame = '#999999',
    legend.show = FALSE)
```

The current output where I require the cells **other** than blue and red, to be **transparent**:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the areas with values in raster 1 do not have values in raster 2 so the color for the first layer shows in NA areas in the second when you combine them. In, addition, set **colorNA = NULL instead of NA**

```
tm_shape(raster2) +
tm_raster(
n = 3,
colorNA = NULL,
alpha = 0.5,
palette = "Reds")
```

[image: A Single layer showing the NA values as transparent in layer 1]

[image: Layer 2]

Now when you combine both rasters in one plot, take out the **frame =  '#999999'** code in the tm_layout bit :

[image: Combined]